# JavaScript undo not working properly. it removes all the previous actions at a time, not only the latest action

Tags: javascript, arrays

in my javascript drawing board i'm trying to implement an Undo function. this is my current code

```
const canvasStates = []; // Stack to store canvas states for undo functionality
let currentCanvasStateIndex = -1; // Index of the current canvas state

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
    setCanvasBackground();
    currentCanvasStateIndex = 0;
    
    const initialCanvasState = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    canvasStates.push(initialCanvasState);

    updateUndoButtonState();
});

const undoBtn = document.getElementById("undo");

undoBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (currentCanvasStateIndex > 0) {
        currentCanvasStateIndex--; // Move back to the previous canvas state
        const previousState = canvasStates[currentCanvasStateIndex];
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.putImageData(previousState, 0, 0);
        
        updateUndoButtonState();
    }
});

function handleMouseUp() {
    clicked = false;
    const currentCanvasState = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    currentCanvasStateIndex++; // Move to the next canvas state
    canvasStates.splice(currentCanvasStateIndex); // Remove any states after the current index
    canvasStates.push(currentCanvasState);
    
    updateUndoButtonState();
}

function updateUndoButtonState() {
    undoBtn.disabled = currentCanvasStateIndex <= 0;
}
```

but when I try to undo something it removes two previous actions at a time.

As an example, imagine I draw a rectangle and then a circle. When i click undo it should remove the circle only, but in my case it removes the both circle and the rectangle...

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Add `console.log()` calls to your functions so you can see how many times they're called.

Comment: Unless you have something that automatically triggers a click on the undo button, the code shown will only remove one state at a time ... Another explanation would be, your code adding the eventhandler is executed multiple times and thus, your trigger is executed multiple times even if you click only once.